# Netbeans autocomplete only writes one word when pressing tab instead of the full sentence

Tags: java, netbeans

I am using Netbeans 11.2. Basically I want to use a method called `getNext()` and when I type for example `variable.g` and wait for the autocomplete, then the first option is `getClass()`. I just press the down arrow key to select `getNext()` and I press tab, but the autocomplete only writes `get` (meaning now I have `variable.get`) and it selects again the first option `getClas()`, and I have to press down arrow key again to select `getNext()` to write the full sentence.

Is there a way to make autocomplete write `getNext()` in just one tab press?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no direct way to resolve this, because autocompletion is working correctly. There are quite a few possibilities with **`.g`**, **`.get`**, etc., and NetBeans has no way of knowing which option you want, so it has to show them all, and let you pick.

However, there is a simple workaround: you can easily create a new code template. Then, if you enter an abbreviation of your choosing, and press [tab], that abbreviation will be replaced with the text **`getNext();`** as follows:

- Navigate to **Tools > Options > Editor > Code Templates** and select *Java* from the **Language** drop list.
- You will see a table with columns titled **Abbreviation** and **Expanded Text**. For example, there is an entry with the abbreviation "*En*" and its associated expanded text is "*${no-indent}Enumeration*".
- All you need to do is add an entry in that table for **`getNext();`**.

To do that:

- Click the **New** button to open the **New Code Template** dialog.
- Enter an unused abbreviation in the **Abbreviation** field, and click **OK**. I chose ***yy***.
- In the **Expanded Text** textbox enter the value you want to be generated. In your case this would simply be **`getNext();`**.
- Finally click **OK** to close the **Options** window.

This screen shot shows the abbreviation **`yy`** mapped to the expanded text **`getNext();`**:

[image: New Template Screen]

Then, in your edit window just type **yy** and press tab to generate **`getNext();`**.

Notes:

- I noticed that after generating the expanded text, the code completion window is displayed. I don't know why that happens, but close it by pressing the escape key. So in my example you would enter `yy[tab][esc]` to generate **`getNext();`**
- The syntax shown in some of the other templates are more complex than this example because NetBeans uses FreeMarker for as its template engine, but for your case just specifying the text to be inserted is all that is needed.